bisector of A intersects the segment of foots from B, C.
Stuck on unusual problem.
given $\triangle ABC$, E and F are feets of perpendiculars from A and B to BC  and AC (let AE=h and BF=k).j-bisector of angle BCA. j intersects EF and AB at M and N (let AN=a, NB=b, MN=d and CN=c). Perpendicular bisector of BA meets circumcircle of ABC at H and T, j go through H.
Proof that:
AE * NB = MN * TB

I have transformed the equation asked in to: dc=2hkab. (assuming: AB=x, BC=y, TL=l, HB=n look up the immage in the link)
I did the following: I wanted to express l in terms of different variables. I used the fact that: nl=(a+b)R (R-radius of circumcircle)
Which is true considering that AB and TH are perpendicular and the angel HBT is right angle. First repraced n: By the similarity of triangles CAH and CNB you have: n=(ax)/c. Then you expres R like this: R=(a+b)xy/4S (S-surface of triangle ABC).
Then You plug R and n and after reducing you get: l=(xc)/(4Sb). Next I just pluged new form of l into question and redused a few more things. From that point on can not make progres.
Mayby the lema that EBHM lays on a circle woud be useful but I am not sure about that.



Hint: The angle bisector at $A$ has length $d$ satisfying $d^2 = bc[(b+c)^2 - a^2]/(b+c)^2$. This allows you to express all the 4 lengths in terms of the original triangle's side lengths and angles, then it's just algebraic manipulation from there.

thanks! that realy helped me to move forvard. But I stil can not compleat the proof becaus of a weird d parameter. I have transformed the initial question in: kh * AB^2=(xy+cos(alfa))(1-cos(alfa)) where alfa=ACB

I suspect there's an error in your working. I expect the expression to be homogeneous, so a term like $xy + \cos \alpha$ which mixes lengths and angles is very surprising to me. IE If we double the lengths of the triangle, then this expression doesn't increase quadratically. $\quad$ I've shown the calculations that I did.


Hint: in figure $BP=MN$, we Draw a circle over points T, P and N. We reflect ABC and AE about a perpendicular onBC at C.So $A'_1E'=AE$. Also $RE'||BA"_1$ and $BQ=AE$. Now all you need to do is showing that $RQ||E'A'_1$.. In this case in blue circle we will have:
$(PB=MN)\times TB=NB\times (BQ=E'A'_1=AE)$

Since the lengths seem somewhat random, and I don't immediately see a nice way of connecting them up, let's just express the sides in terms of $a, b, c, \alpha, \beta, \gamma$ of $ABC$ and hope we can make the equation work out, which we should if it is true. (IE brute force algebraic manipulation)
Let's calculate the lengths:

$AE:$ $AE = AB \sin \beta = c \sin \beta$.
$NB:$ $\frac{NB}{AB} = \frac{a}{a+b}$ by angle bisector theorem, so $ NB = \frac{ac}{a+b}$.
$TB:$ $\frac{TB}{ \sin 90^\circ - \gamma/2} = 2R $ and $\frac{AB}{\sin \gamma} = 2R$ by extended sine rule, so $ TB   = \frac{c}{2 \sin \gamma/2} $.
$MN: $

By length of angle bisector, $CN^2 = \frac{ab[(a+b)^2 - c^2 ]}{(a+b)^2} = \frac{ 2a^2b^2(1 + \cos \gamma}{(a+b)^2} = \frac{ 4 a^2b^2\cos^2 \gamma/2} {(a+b)^2}$. So $CN = \frac{ 2ab \cos \gamma/2 } { (a+b)}$
By angle chasing, $CME, CNA$ are similar triangles with 2 angles of $\gamma/2, \alpha$, so $CM = \frac{CE}{CA} CN = \cos \gamma CN$.
Hence $MN = CN - CM = ( 1 - \cos \gamma) \frac{ 2ab \cos \gamma/2 } { (a+b)}$.



Now, we can substitute them in to get:
$$ \begin{array} { l l l} 
& AE \cdot NB = MN \cdot TB \\
\Leftrightarrow & 
\frac{c \sin \beta \cdot ac } { a+b} = \frac{c(1 - \cos \gamma)2ab \cos \gamma/2}{2\sin \gamma/2(a+b)} 
\\ \Leftrightarrow  & c \sin \beta \sin \gamma/2= b (2 \sin^2 \gamma/2) \cos \gamma/2 
\\  \Leftrightarrow & c \sin \beta = b \sin \gamma. \end{array}$$
The last statement is just sine rule, hence $AE \cdot NB = MN \cdot TB$.
